# Serialize objects as HTTP Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-serialization

I am using REST API as part of my project and I need to pass request parameters from my application.

E.g To create a user I need to pass First Name, Last Name, EmailId, Password etc

And the Request structure is

```
 `<Request>
   <Users>
    <User>
     <FirstName>alice</FirstName>
     <LastName>cullen</LastName>
     <MiddleInitial>U</MiddleInitial>
     <EmailId>alice@sampleorg.com</EmailId>
     <UserName>alicec</UserName>
     <Password>ffsdfsfd</Password>
    </User>
  </Users>
</Request>`
```

I get required inputs from createuser.aspx page and convert it as User object.

Now I need to convert the user object as Request so the same can be passed to API Routes.

Is Serialization the only to do this or there are any other methods I can do effectively?

**EDIT:** Is http://restsharp.org/ a solution?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Do you want to send the data from the client (browser) to the api routes or do you want to pass the received data to an API Route. If you do it server side and just want to forward the received data, then Restsharp is indeed a good solution.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer yes, the posted data are in form of objects in server side, I need to pass them to api routes.

Comment: Also @Schadensbegrenzer what would be the way to  pass the form data directly to api routes?

Comment: From the server side you should use Restsharp. It's handy and does the job well. I am using it in my projects, too. The direct way would be using jQuery for example. Documentation for posting data via jquery you'll find here. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer Thanks! Let me give a try.

Comment: by the way... JSON.stringify (as posted by @jithiil) would be a valid way to serialize javascript objects into a json data!

Answer (score -1):

var formData = JSON.stringify($("#createuserForm").serializeArray());

and pass this data as Json binary data

Comment: -1: Not clear how JSON related to XML requested by OP... Maybe some explanation could help.